# What's wrong with this code? (Cat class)

Tags: java

When I compile , I obtain: error, expected ; after meow(). What's wrong with this code

```
public class Cat
{ 
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String name;
        String colour;
        int age;

        Cat c = new Cat();
        c.nome = "Muffin";

        System.out.println(c.name);

        meow(){
            System.out.println("Meow! Meow!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [you are mixing local variables and member variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: Everything is wrong with it. Look at it now after I've properly formatted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you defined the properties of `Cat` as local variables of your main method instead of as members of the class.

And your `meow` method shouldn't be inside the main method, and it should have a return type.

```
 public class Cat
 { 
     String name;
     String colour;
     int age;

     public static void main(String[]args)
     {    
        Cat c = new Cat();
        c.name = "Muffin";

        System.out.println(c.name);
     }

     void meow() 
     {
         System.out.println("Meow! Meow!");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the patient. I'm a newbie and I make a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be "trying" defining a method with in a method, which is illegal in Java

It should be more like...

```
public class Cat
{ 
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String name;
        String colour;
        int age;

        Cat c = new Cat();
        c.nome = "Muffin";

        System.out.println(c.name);
        c.meow();
    }

    public void meow(){
        System.out.println("Meow! Meow!");
    }
}
```

Now, having said that, the properties of `Cat` are been defined as local variables within the main method and aren't actually part of the `Cat` class, the should be defined as part of the class (or as instance fields)

```
public class Cat
{ 

    String name;
    String colour;
    int age;

    public static void main(String[]args){

        Cat c = new Cat();
        c.nome = "Muffin";

        System.out.println(c.name);
        c.meow();
    }

    public void meow(){
        System.out.println("Meow! Meow!");
    }
}
```

Okay, look better, but there's still one more problem, the field nome is undefined in `Cat`, and probably should be name

```
c.name = "Muffin";
```

The next thing you'll want to learn about is protecting the classes field values and managing access via methods instead, commonly known as [encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much. I use your help for another code with the same problems. You're very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes inside of this class. So lets take a closer look:

1) You've defined the properties of Cat inside the main Function, but what you want is to have them as object attributes. The static context of the main method is for usage without an concrete object (and is for every instantiated class the same (value as well as method)

2)You assigned to c.nome instead of c.name

3) meow() misses the return type (which is necessary unless for constructors (which meow isn't))

4) meow() must be outside of the main method

```
public class Cat {
    String name;
    String colour;
    int age;

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Cat c = new Cat();
        c.name = "Muffin";
        System.out.println(c.name);
    }

    void meow() {
        System.out.println("Meow! Meow!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank very much for the point 1, 3 and 4. For the 2 I'm italian and name in italian is nome :) . I'm a newbie and I make a lot of mistakes...

Comment: We all started once ;)